# Why Oracle 11g installs in folder C:\app\<name_of_user>

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, windows

Just curious, now Oracle 11g installs by default in folder C:\app\

Why? Before, Oracle was installed by default in folder C:\oracle... Why now is created "app" folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is to harmonize the unix and windows file system structure. On Windows the structure is `/<mountpoint>/app/<username>`. On Windows it is `<DRIVELETTER>:\app\<username>`. `<mountpoint>` is a directory name (Oracle prefers `u01`,`u02`,...), `<DRIVELETTER>` is `C`, `D` ... and `<username>` is the username of the Oracle software owner. The [reason](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24321/appendix_ofa.htm#g641220) for `/<mountpoint>/app/<username>` is that Oracle assumes the unix home directory in something like `<mountpoint>/home/<username>`. Then all the base directories of the `oracle` user have the structure  `/*/*/oracle`. Choosing `<DRIVELETTER>:\app\<username>` (or `/<mountpoint>/app/<username>`) instead of `<DRIVELETTER>:\<username>` also avoids potentially naming conflicts. In contrast to  `<DRIVELETTER>:\app` the directory `<DRIVELETTER>:\` does not contain only directories that equals usernames.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the documentation, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/ofa.htm). See "B.2 Changes to the Optimal Flexible Architecture for Oracle Database".

Comment: Sorry, but on that document I don't find a reason why switching from C:\oracle to C:\app\<username>. It just states that from now on it will be so.

Comment: Why do Oracle, who actually write the software, need a reason to change paths for software installation? I don't mean to be rude, but your question and reply to my answer is more pointless than the reason Oracle changed their directory structure.